# How to use Apache storm as Complex Event Processor

Tags: apache, apache-storm, esper, complex-event-processing

I have been looking for awhile on how to use apache storm as CEP, but it seems there is two concepts (Stream processing and Complex event processing) where in CEP you can write sql-like queries and they are executed on the data stream, like ESPER , but I can't find any similar thing in apache storm, does this is mean apache storm is a data stream processor not a CEP ?

Answer (score 0):

Storm is a distributed computation platform, general-purpose, designed to handle streaming data. I think many use it for taking an incoming stream and writing it to some database or No-SQL. There is a Storm-Esper library for running Esper inside a Storm bolt.

Answer (score 0):

Storm provide a high level api named trident,that include sql-like api.It's feature is the micro-batch,just like spark streaming. But I think the low api which is storm's core can do what you want almost all.